# Dynamic Client IP in freeRADIUS where client is identified by secret

Tags: radius, freeradius

I have multiple locations sending RADIUS requests to my server. These are currently configured as:

```
client any_client {
    ipaddr = x.x.x.x
    netmask = 32
    secret = client_secret
    shortname = name
}
```

However some clients have ISP that changes their IP address. Moreover, multiple clients are using the same ISP so the clients don't have a unique subnet each. What I want to do is allow all connections from a certain IP range, however still have separate secrets for each client and then still assign the correct shortname for accounting purposes.

Is what I want even possible in freeradius?

Comment: I don't see this as linked to FreeRadius. I'm not sure why there would be an expectation this would work.